# RadioGroup member buttons keep changing ID when I switch activity

Tags: android, view, widget, radio-group

I have 2 activities which navigate to each other back and forward. Both has a RadioGroup inside them. The problem is the first activity has RadioGroup ids as :1 , 2 ,3 ,4 and second activity has ids as : 5, 6, 7, 8. But when I switch back to the first activity again, the ids change to: 9, 10, 11, 12. Is there a solution for this?

Here is how I define my grouop:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/leftRadioGroup"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="LED OFF"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        />
    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Position LED"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        />
   <RadioButton
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Force LED"
       android:layout_margin="7dp"
       android:textSize="10sp"
       android:fontFamily="serif"
       />
</RadioGroup>
```

and here is how I set click listener on them:

```
  leftRadio = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.leftRadioGroup);
    leftRadio.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(i==1) {
                leftLed = 0;

            }
            else if(i==2) {
                leftLed = 1;

            }
            else {
                leftLed=3;

            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why you didn't set android:id to buttons and use them in if statement?

Comment: Have a look at [this example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `android:id` attribute in your `RadioButton` and check this `id` in `onCheckedChanged()` method.

Example:

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And in `RadioGroup.setOncheckedChangedListener`:

```
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(i==R.id.radioButton1) {
            leftLed = 0;
        }
        else if(i==R.id.radioButton2) {
            leftLed = 1;
        }
        else {
            leftLed=3;
        }
    }
```

You may want to see [Android RadioGroup Example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/radiogroup/android-radiogroup-example/)